# 'home' is not a registered namespace Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create an a way that you can get the product information by licking on a product and then loading that information into 1 html file, I looked up a couple of tutorials up and they al says this code works, but for me it gives me an error named "'home' is not a registered namespace Django" does anyone know how to fix this?

views.py (home app directory

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import albums
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView




def album(request):
    return render(request, 'home/album.html')

def artists(request):
    return render(request, 'home/artists.html')

class homeview(ListView):
    model = albums
    template_name = "home/home.html"

class albuminfo(DetailView):
    model = albums
    template_name = "home/AlbumInfo.html"
```

models.py

```
    class albums(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.TextField()
        release_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        genre = models.CharField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default2.jpg', upload_to='album_pics')
        slug = models.SlugField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("home:AlbumInfo", kwargs={
                'slug': self.slug
            })
```

urls.py

```
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homeview.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('albums/', views.album, name='Nartonmusic-album'),
    path('artists/', views.artists, name='Nartonmusic-artists'),
    path('albuminfo/<slug>/', views.albuminfo.as_view(), name='AlbumInfo')
]
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %} 
{%block content%} 
{% for album in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{{album.get_absolute_url}}">{{ album.title}} </a></li>
{% endfor %} 
{%endblock%}
```

can somebody help my out?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use

```
... reverse('home:AlbumInfo' ....)
```

then you need to add in urls.py

```
app_name = 'home'
```